# Xorg conflict with grub on 16.04

Tags: unity, grub2, nvidia, xorg

I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 16.04.

I have a Nvidia GTX 960m.

The Nvidia drivers from their site and from the Ubuntu repos both cause me problems (not the least of which being blurry lines when smooth scrolling in Firefox), and want to use the normal xorg drivers.

These drivers work fine, but the system freezes on startup when they're turned on. The workaround is to manually enter the grub menu and add "nomodeset."

However, if I add nomodeset to the /etc/default/grub file, it still freezes.

Weird thing:

I have also tried removing "quiet splash" from the menu, and this does allow the system to boot, but when it does it is a super-lag type situation, where just loading a menu takes 30 seconds.

I am certain this is just some grub issue which is easy to solve, since I can boot fine after manually entering the grub menu on boot. Presumably I am editing the /etc/default/grub file wrongly.

Thanks!